# How to access Private Api gateway from on-premises server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc-peering

How to connect private apigateway to onpremises server?
I got [this doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/direct-connect-private-api-gateway/) and following it, but not able to access after creating vpce with public Dns Name.

Comment: VPN is a usual solution.

Comment: means  I have my personal laptop can I consume private apigateway using site-to-site vpn ! please confirm ,if yes thn provide some solution .